# colab restart inn between cnn training

Tags: tensorflow, operating-system, google-colaboratory

my colab restart after showing memory error.
I  am trying to train cnn model on google colab notebook but after fist epoch my notebook restart itself by showing the error of memory allocation issue.
I was running the same one day before and it was running fine.

Logs are attached here.

Comment: Please read about how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrase and paste relevant logs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be running out of memory in google Colab.
One way to get around this might be to use your own computer. The method for this with anaconda is:

1. open anaconda
2. type in to anaconda: pip install jupyter
3. Once it is downloaded, type: jupyter notebook
4. this then opens a webpage, in the webpage there is a dropdown (I think called new) which you should click on, then click on terminal
5. in the terminal, you should type in (all on one line):  jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8889 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
6. There will then be 3 output links, copy the second one.
7. back in colab, click the dropdown in the top right next to connect, then click connect to local runtime
8. Then input the copied URL into the prompt, then connect.