# further training a DL model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I cannot train my model with all my datasets in colab, because of RAM capability, so i was thinking to do something like:

```
model.save('model_trained_on_25%_ofmydata.h5')

new_model=load_model('model_trained_on_25%_ofmydata.h5')
new_model.fit(remaining_50%_ofmydata)
new_model.save(remaining_50%_ofmydata)

new_model2=load_model('remaining_50%_ofmydata.h5')
new_model2.fit(remaining_75%_ofmydata)
new_model2.save(remaining_75%_ofmydata)

new_model3=load_model('remaining_75%_ofmydata.h5')
new_model3.fit(remaining_100%_ofmydata)
new_model3.save(remaining_100%_ofmydata)
```

I have read about **catastrophic forgetting**, that the model forget what it learns from previous old data, i don't want to retrain only on new data, how i can achieve that the model doesn't forget what it learns from previous trainings ?

Comment: Are you unable to just use `flow_from_directory()`?

Comment: that's new to me, I read the documentation "it Takes the path to a directory & generates batches of augmented data",  i don't have augmented data, only raw images data

Comment: and the problem with colab i cannot run it for long time, so i need to stop training after around 5 hours and recontinue training

Comment: You don't have to augment data with it. You can load images as is.

Comment: You can also estimate how many epochs would train for 5h, then save  the model on whatever epoch it reaches, or slightly before (a checkpoint). Then reload the model with the saved weights and continue training.

Comment: I think your solution would work. In the past i personally have used `model.save_weights('directory')` then `model.load_weights('directory')`, so maybe also try that? Also if you are using a online colab session, hosting it on your own computer may avoid the issue, there is a guide for that i answered in the past here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540344/colab-restart-inn-between-cnn-training/72578827#72578827 and the official website for that is here: (warning, its a bit crap) https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html